# How to create single app between iOS, Android & Web using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For example: creating a  mobile app with camera.It should support only in mobile. web app doesn't have camera feature.How to write a code for both web and mobile in single source code.Is there any plugin is available in the market...please suggest some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Check this article https://medium.com/kuralabs-engineering/reactive-core-architecture-for-react-native-and-react-applications-d590daf4ef8a they really explain and they have examples of how you can accomplish that.

You must have two different projects, web and native, and then create a separate project with the shared Redux store or utils to reuse, something like this:

[image]

Your project can have this structure:

```
├── web
├── mobile
└── shared
```

and then on your package.json of your native and web projects, you can add `shared` as a dependency:

```
"shared": "file: ../shared"
```

then on your mobile or web projects, you can import your shared code like this:

```js
import { someUtilFuncition } from 'shared/utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Expo now supports react-native-web.](https://blog.expo.io/expo-cli-and-sdk-web-support-beta-d0c588221375) Using that, along with react-native-web's extended [`Platform`](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/storybook/?selectedKind=APIs&selectedStory=Platform&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0) module, you can create platform-specific code using `Platform.OS` and `Platform.select`.